# Debian 8 + Subversion + Redmine

Tags: linux, debian, svn, tortoise-svn

Настроил и запустил связку Debian 8 + Subversion + Redmine, все хорошо, но конект при работе с свн нестабильный. При скачивании или заливании постоянно валится ошибка

> Error retrieving REPORT: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.

Подскажите куда копать?

Так же выскакивает частенько ошибка

> Error: GET request on
>   Error:  '/svn/...........'
>   Error:  failed: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: вероятно, доступ к svn у вас осуществляется через веб-сервер. в первую очередь имеет смысл просмотреть его логи. если это `apache`, то, скорее всего, они находятся в каталоге `/var/log/apache2/`

Comment: Так и есть, доступ через apache2

Часть лога

http://joxi.ru/823nL49SlPjWmO?d=1

Comment: приведены две строки про отсутствие доступа. у меня есть предположение, что в конфигурации apache для этого сайта что-то не в порядке с разграничением доступа. может быть, смешаны старые директивы (order+deny+allow) с новой (require). подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time) (примеры про access control).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin перенесите ваши комментарии в ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то наталкивался на глюки в работе  SVN через Apache WebDAV, долго ломал голову, откуда берутся ошибки, пока не отключил `mod_evasive` (пакет `libapache2-mod-evasive`). Как выяснилось, он блокировал запросы клиента SVN, считая их то-ли флудом, то-ли ДДоСом.

Answer (score 0):

в приведенных автором вопроса двух строках из логов речь идёт про отсутствие доступа.

у меня есть предположение, что в конфигурации apache для этого сайта что-то не в порядке с разграничением доступа. может быть, смешаны старые директивы (order+deny+allow) с новой (require). подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time) (примеры про access control).